# Looking for basic R code to list number of CPUs and memory available on machine

Tags: r

I am running an R code set on different machines and would like to print the number of CPUs and memory available as I report elapsed time it took to run the program. I'd like this to work on various OS's. I plan on optimizing the code accordingly (with doSNOW for example) based on these stats. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to work with system calls. You would need a different system call for each OS. See: http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/system.html If you just want to see the time a function takes, you can use `system.time(myfunction())`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
library(parallel)
detectCores()
#[1] 24

# for memory in MB's on Windows
memory.limit()
#[1] 98293

# on linux maybe process this info (not sure if there is an R function)
system('cat /proc/meminfo')
```

Answer (score 2):

For the number of cores, you can use `detectCores()` in the package `parallel`, as mentioned earlier. To circumvent the OS problem, you could cheat by using something like this:

```
 if (Sys.info()[1] == "Windows"){
    command for windows
 } else {
    command for linux (or other OS)
 }
```